# jQuery $.ajax fails in ie9/FF when using statusCode, fix?

Tags: jquery

Submitting the following $.ajax, which is indeed executing but fails silently without any error. IE9 dev tools don't spring an error and fiddler shows no traffic.

I can confirm the code does indeed execute since the "processing" bit does appear on the screen. However the rest seems to just fail. I am *not* doing x-domain.

```
$('.signupMsg').html("<img src='/assets/img/load-black.gif' /> Processing...");
var data = $('#emailForm').serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://example.com/proxy/emaillist',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    statusCode: {
        200: function(msg) {
            $('.signupBlock').html("&nbsp;<br><strong>Thank you!</strong><br>You will be hearing from us soon.");
            $('#emailForm').remove();
        },
        500: function(msg) {
            $('.signupBlock').html("&nbsp;<br><strong>Something went wrong.</strong><br>Sorry about that, please <a href='/'>refresh</a> and try again.");
            $('#emailForm').remove();
        },
            404: function(msg) {
                    $('.signupBlock').html("&nbsp;<br><strong>Something went wrong.</strong><br>Sorry about that, please <a href='/'>refresh</a> and try again.");
                    $('#emailForm').remove();
            },
        503: function(msg) {
            $('.signupBlock').html("&nbsp;<br><strong>Server temporarily down.</strong><br>Sorry about that, please <a href='/'>refresh</a> and try again.");
            $('#emailForm').remove();
        },
        400: function(msg) {
            $('.signupMsg').html("<span style='color:red'>Email validation failed, please try again.</span>");
        }
    }
```

});

Using jQ 1.7.2. The code executes fine in Google Chrome but fails in IE7-9 and FF. Is statusCode not supported in older browsers?

Or should I just switch to SuperAgent for code response support? http://visionmedia.github.com/superagent/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's not a fix for jQuery but it is a fix for the AJAX call.

I just switched to SuperAgent and got the same thing working:

```
request
.post('url/to/example')
.send(data)
.end(function(res){
    if(res.status==200) {
        $('.signupBlock').html("&nbsp;<br><strong>Thank you!</strong><br>You will be hearing from us soon.");
        $('#emailForm').remove();                           
    }
    if(res.status==500) {
        $('.signupBlock').html("&nbsp;<br><strong>Something went wrong.</strong><br>Sorry about that, please <a href='/'>refresh</a> and try again.");
        $('#emailForm').remove();
    }
    if(res.status==404) {
        $('.signupBlock').html("&nbsp;<br><strong>Something went wrong.</strong><br>Sorry about that, please <a href='/'>refresh</a> and try again.");
        $('#emailForm').remove();
    }
    if(res.status==503) {
        $('.signupBlock').html("&nbsp;<br><strong>Server temporarily down.</strong><br>Sorry about that, please <a href='/'>refresh</a> and try again.");
        $('#emailForm').remove();
    }
    if(res.status==400) {
        $('.signupMsg').html("<span style='color:red'>Email validation failed, please try again.</span>");
    }
});
```